# как делать через css так чтоб когда в div id="content" пустое содержание то div class="style1" получил display none

Tags: css

у меня такая конструкция

```
<div class="style1">

<div id="content">($CONTENT$)</div>

</div>
```

как делать через css так чтоб когда в div id="content" пустое содержание то div class="style1" получил display none

я попробовал разные псеудоелементы

:empty;  (not) и так далее

но не достиг результата ...

Comment: через js делается

Comment: код от движка??

Comment: cms datalife engine DLE

Comment: <div class="movie-page clearfix"><div id="dle-content">{content}</div></div>

Comment: пишите любые решение ... через js, css

Answer (score 0):

На Jquery

```js
// для "визуализации"
$('.content').each(function(){
  if(!$(this).html()) $(this).closest('.style1').hide();
});

// для конкретно вашего кода
/*
  let content = $('#content');
  if(!content.html()) content.closest('.style1').hide();
*/
```

```css
.style1 {
  display: block;
  background: red;
  min-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="style1">
  <div class="content">($CONTENT$)</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="style1">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```